# const_cast to "void pointer" from "const T pointer" fails

Tags: c++

Why does the following code fails to compile?

```
CFDictionaryRef dictionary;
```

[CFDictionaryApplyFunction](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1516745-cfdictionaryapplyfunction?language=objc)(dict, set, const_cast< void * >(dictionary));

```
 error: const_cast from 'CFDictionaryRef' (aka 'const __CFDictionary *') to 'void *' is not allowed
    CFDictionaryApplyFunction(scoped, setDictionary, const_cast<void *>(dictionary));
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I set c-style type cast to void * it works fine

[CFDictionaryApplyFunction](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1516745-cfdictionaryapplyfunction?language=objc)(dict, set, ( void * )dictionary);

Comment: Because `const_cast` casts ***only*** the `const`ness of a type. If you want to cast between a `const` pointer of one type and a mutable pointer of another type, first you need to cast the `const`-ness, using `const_cast`, and then do `reinterpret_cast`, to finish the job. The fact that two casts are necessary is a honking red flag that something is fundamentally wrong with the code that has to do this, anyway. Properly designed and written code never needs to do that. Whatever your real problem is, it's not that.

Comment: A `const_cast` and `static_cast` would do.

Comment: What are the argument types for CFDictionaryApplyFunction method?

Answer (score 2):

Do `reinterpret_cast<void *>(const_cast< __CFDictionary * >(dictionary))`

`const_cast` is only designed to cast between `const` pointers or references and their non-`const` equivalents. To convert to a different type (`void*` in your case), you need to use `reinterpret_cast`. `reinterpret_cast` basically "reinterprets" the same sequence of bits as a different type. However, it is not allowed to cast away constness, so you need to use both casts together.

EDIT: As @AnT points out, since the target is `void *`, you can use `static_cast` instead of `reinterpret_cast`. In fact, it is considered safer, because the standard guarantees that you get the same address as a result. `reinterpret_cast`, on the other hand, only guarantees that the original value will be obtained by `reinterpret_cast` ing the result of the first cast back. However, this applies only for a restricted set of conversions (`void *`, Base-derived class pairs). `reinterpret_cast` is more general, although you are relying on the compiler to do the reasonable thing.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Firstly, there's no need to involve `reinterpret_cast` for casting to `void *`. `static_cast` can do that. There's no need for "reinterpretation" of any kind here. Secondly, "reinterpret" in `reinterpret_cast` does not refer to reinterpreting bits of the value being converted. It refers to reinterpreting the value being pointed by pointer (or referenced by reference). Since in this case one of the types is `void *`, there's really no meaningful "reinterpretation" involved, since `void` objects do not exist.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I was refering to this:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast